# Shorthand if ? return : null

Tags: javascript, refactoring, ternary-operator, shorthand, shorthand-if

I want to achieve this:

```
 if (full) {
      return
    }
    else{
      // nuthin
    }
```

But shorter, something like:

```
full ? return : null;
```

But that doesn't work..

I could do:

```
if (full) { return }
```

But I like the ternary more

I expected something like `full ? return` to work...

I basically want to break out of the current function when the value is true...
Are there any better/working shorthands available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this is as short as it gets:

```
 if full return
```

Answer (score 5):

The arguments of a ternary are *expressions* **not** *statements*.

`return;` is a statement so what you're proposing is not syntatically valid.

Your `if` statement is about as terse as you can make it: especially if you remove unnecessary braces.

Answer (score 0):

## Explainations

If you only want the test if true, you can use the logical AND operator `&&` like so:

`index.js`:

```
(function(){
    var full=true;
    full&&alert('Glass is full');
})();
```

Note that in this example, nothing will happen in case `var full=false;`.

## Source-code

[JSFiddle source-code.](https://jsfiddle.net/j5r2meys/)

[Codepen source-code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egqbwp)

[Pastebin source-files](http://pastebin.com/2jc94E7L)